# como hacer "Foo().anotherFoo()"

Tags: javascript, typescript

quiero saber como funciona/crear esto de las funciones tipo `foo().sumFoo(2)` es decir que si el resultado de `foo()` es "n" al unirlo con la función `sumFoo(x)` sea igual a n + x.

Es decir:

```js
foo(n){
  return parseInt(n);
}

fooSum(x){
  return foo() + x;
}
```

pero en vez de llamar a `foo()` dentro de `fooSum()` que `fooSum()` tome automaticamente el valor retornado de `foo()` al colocarlo tipo: `foo().fooSum()`

Ejemplo de funciones que hacen algo parecido:

`toString()`

`firebase.firestore().collection('db_name').doc()`

**¿Cómo se llaman ese tipo de funciones y como puedo crearlas?**

Answer (score 2):

Hay varias formas de hacer esto, veremos cómo hacerlo con [**programación orientada a objetos**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object-oriented_JS), lo que haremos básicamente es que cuando se llame la función `foo` instanciaremos una clase poniendo el resultado de la función como dato dentro de la instancia de la clase, y devolveremos la clase, de esta manera, la instancia tendrá el resultado y podrás llamar métodos como `anotherFoo` que están dentro de la clase

```js
function foo(n) {
  // Aquí tenemos la clase
  class fooHandler {
    // Definimos el constructor
    constructor(n) {
      // Aquí ponemos el resultado de la función
      this.funcResult = n;
    }
    // Ponemos otros métodos
    anotherFoo(n) {
      // Devolvemos lo que queramos
      // En este caso una suma
      return this.funcResult + n;
    }
  }
  // Instanciamos la clase y la devolvemos
  return new fooHandler(n);
}

console.log(
  foo(2).anotherFoo(1), // 3
  foo(4).anotherFoo(57) // 61
);
```

También podrías usar una función que devuelva un objeto, este objeto tendrá los métodos que quieras nombrar, esta opción es más viable y óptima para usuarios que recién están iniciando y/o no comprenden del todo la programación orientada a objetos.

```js
function foo(n) {
  const fooHandler = {
    anotherFoo(n2) {
      // Devolvemos la suma
      return n + n2;
    }
  };
  return fooHandler;
}

console.log(
  foo(2).anotherFoo(4), // 6
  foo(4).anotherFoo(57) // 61
);
```

---

Con respecto a las funciones anidadas, es muchísimo más viable la segunda opción, te ahorras muchas líneas de código y tu código se hace más fácil de entender

Y aquí tenemos otro problema, es que tenemos que definir un método en el que va a finalizar nuestro sistema de anidamiento, sea `multy` devolveremos un resultado, mientras tanto siempre se devolverá un objeto para que podamos seguir llamando a `anotherFoo` cuantas veces queramos, o si no, devolver un objeto hasta en `multy` para poder seguir usando otros métodos

```js
function foo(num) {
  // Definir el objeto
  const fooHandler = {
    anotherFoo(n) {
      // Devolver otro objeto
      return {
        ...fooHandler,
        multiply(n1) {
          // Aquí para añadir métodos específicos
          return (num + n) * n1;
        }
      };
      // Si deseas devolver el mismo objeto sin métodos específicos, solo pon: return fooHandler;
    }
  };
  // Devolver el objeto
  return fooHandler;
}

console.log(foo(3).anotherFoo(6).multiply(4)); // (3 + 6) * 4 = 36
console.log(foo(3).anotherFoo(6).anotherFoo(4)); // Aquí devolvemos un objeto para que podamos seguir usando las otras funciones
console.log(foo(3).anotherFoo(6).anotherFoo(4).multiply(5)) // (3 + 6) * 5 = 35
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias @Rodrigo! En el caso de querer seguir añadiendo funciones tipo: `foo(4).anotherFoo(57).multy(2)`  ¿Cómo podría hacerlo? ( ya lo intente añadiéndolo debajo de `anotherFoo(n)` :( pero no me funciono )

Comment: @IsaacMartinez He actualizado mi respuesta, concretamente en la última sección, se elabora lo que solicitas. ¿He respondido a tu pregunta?

Comment: ¡Así es! muchas gracias. Pero tengo entendido que no podre quedarme con el resultado de `foo().anotherFoo()` en el caso que lo necesite, o quedarme solo el de `foo()` Pero a pesar de todo, tu respuesta me ha aclarado muchas cosas, seguiré investigando a ver que puedo encontrar para solucionar eso.

Comment: al final logre hacer [esto](https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-feistel-311xp?file=/src/index.js)